# Cordova - Deprecated attempt to access property 'userAgent' on a non-Navigator object

Tags: javascript, ios, google-maps, cordova

I'm trying to get my Cordova iPhone app working in iOS 8.1

Working fine in 7, since 8 I'm getting the following error:

```
Deprecated attempt to access property 'userAgent' on a non-Navigator object.
```

This is breaking the rendering of the app in page so I need a fix. I've taken a look at the various proposed solutions around the web but none seem to work.

Interestingly the error is coming from the JS retrieved from "https://maps.gstatic.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/17/17/main.js". --- perhaps part of the Google Maps API I'm trying to use?

Any help on the matter would be amazing!

Many thanks

Chris

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Which cordova version are you using?

That should be fixed now in the latest version, but if you don't want to update the project, you can change replaceNavigator function to be like this on the cordova.js file (the whole else is new)

```
function replaceNavigator(origNavigator) {
        var CordovaNavigator = function() {};
        CordovaNavigator.prototype = origNavigator;
        var newNavigator = new CordovaNavigator();
        // This work-around really only applies to new APIs that are newer than Function.bind.
        // Without it, APIs such as getGamepads() break.
        if (CordovaNavigator.bind) {
            for (var key in origNavigator) {
                if (typeof origNavigator[key] == 'function') {
                    newNavigator[key] = origNavigator[key].bind(origNavigator);
                } else {
                    (function(k) {
                        Object.defineProperty(newNavigator, k, {
                            get: function() {
                                return origNavigator[k];
                            },
                            configurable: true,
                            enumerable: true
                        });
                    })(key);
                }
            }
        }
        return newNavigator;
    }
```

Comment: Can you give more details than just "This didn't work for me.". Cordova version?

Comment: as I said before, give more details, a "didn't work for me" doesn't provide enough information to help you

Comment: My cordova version is 3.1 and as i change replaceNavigator function with given snippet.But getting same error.

Comment: if you are using cordova 3.1, it's possible that your cordova.js is overwritten when you run, this solution is for 2.9.1 and earlier, where people can't update easilly. Just update your project to the latest version

Comment: you need this 3 commands to update. "npm install -g cordova"
"cd your_project"
"cordova platform update android"

Comment: I am using worklight for application development.i can not use this command.

Comment: Sorry, I don't use worklight, but is hard to believe IBM hasn't fixed this bug

Answer (score 0):

it looks like a known issue in cordova that can be fixed by updating your cordova version (as well as plugins?)

from [Cordova Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-6911)

> If you want to get the fix simply do the following:
>
> 1. Clone the cordova-js (Version 3.7)
> 2. Grunt the git, this will create all the native js files.
> 3. Replace the cordova.js in your platform_www folder

Comment: I have the latest version of Cordova and Phonegap, still doesn't work, gets this error.