# Worklight : Deprecated attempt to access property 'userAgent' on a non-Navigator object. and SideBar issue

Tags: ios, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, ios8.1

We developed a Hybrid application on Phonegap with the help of IBM worklight 6.1. Worklight is using cordova version 3.1.

My **first problem** is that when I ran my project on IOS 8.1 platform getting by default sidebar on my screen(i.e. surrounded by red line in attached screen shot).I tried to debug but not able to find out the issue.
![sidebar][]
My **second problem** is that on every run i am getting **"Deprecated attempt to access property 'userAgent' on a non-Navigator object."**. I followed this link "[Cordova - Deprecated attempt to access property 'userAgent' on a non-Navigator object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26654877/cordova-deprecated-attempt-to-access-property-useragent-on-a-non-navigator-o)" but still i have same error.

Any help on the matter would be good

Thank you in advance

Comment: What do you want us to do w/out providing any CODE that we can run and debug ourselves? Upload your Worklight project to Dropbox and provide a download link.

Comment: This is big deal for me. How would I share company property Idan.

Comment: Create a new project, without your company confidential etc etc... that still demonstrates the issue. Then share it. This is a programming Q&A website - no one can help you w/out CODE.

Comment: For first Issue:
I created a project worklight platformVersion="6.1.0.01.20140718-1711" and ran on 8.1 but not getting existing issue.So i will share you the project once i encounter the error.

Comment: For Second issue :
I am getting these two error continuously after starting project in emulator.
[Error] Deprecated attempt to access property 'userAgent' on a non-Navigator object.
 request (worklight.js, line 1070)
 initialize (worklight.js, line 1040)
 klass (worklight.js, line 509)
 sendRequest (worklight.js, line 3163)
 initialize (worklight.js, line 3059)
 klass (worklight.js, line 509)
 sendHeartBeat (worklight.js, line 5884)
 onTimerEvent (worklight.js, line 878)
 (anonymous function) (worklight.js, line 941)

Comment: [Error] Deprecated attempt to access property 'userAgent' on a non-Navigator object.
 initialize (worklight.js, line 1209)
 klass (worklight.js, line 509)
 respondToReadyState (worklight.js, line 1143)
 onStateChange (worklight.js, line 1088)
 (anonymous function) (worklight.js, line 941)

Comment: One issue at a time.

Comment: About the second issue - there is no fix for you when using worklight unless you will open a PMR and request a backport of that fix to the used cordova 3.1 version in worklight 6.1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69271/discussion-between-vishal-singh-and-idan-adar).

Comment: ן had a chat with the cordova team and they determine that the error is harmless, so you should focus on providing code to debug for the first issue.

Comment: Where is the problem? all I see is some red title and two input fields; Edit the question and properly explain yourself.

Comment: first open my application in 8.1 and debug with the help of safari in mac.
Then you will see the space in the right hand side as shown in this picture. I am not getting from where that space is coming.
Every time i am getting a sidebar on right hand side. And this issue came only after upgrading to 8.1.

Comment: All the HTML there is auto-generated! and is unavailable to inspection. How exactly do you expect to debug it? Create a /simple/ app.

Comment: My first problem got resolved, I migrated from worklight platformVersion="6.1.0.01.20140718-1711" to platformVersion="6.3.0.00.20150106-1717". But still i am struggling with second issue. Now i am using cordova 3.6.3 but still getting "Deprecated attempt to access property 'userAgent' on a non-Navigator object.".

Comment: Does the error actually prevents something from working? This error is supposed to not affect anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first issue was reported as resolved in the comments after upgrading to MobileFirst Platform 6.3 (which uses Cordova v3.6.3).

The second issue [is a Cordova defect, resolved starting Cordova v3.7](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-6911).
The issue was determined to be harmless as it does not not affect actual execution.

So you case safely ignore it.
However, if you spot related action that *does* fail (you did not specifically make that claim), do mention it. It will then be re-considered if to back-port the fix...

Comment: Second issue creating a bigger issue in application flow.can anyone help me out, what should i do?

Comment: Open a pmr and ask for a fix

Comment: Which cordova version is used in MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.0?

Comment: Cordova 3.7 is used in mfp 7